# SQL query that won't execute

Tags: sql, mysql

I am new to SQL and just at a loss for why this piece of code won't execute. I get know errors but I get no results. No matter how long I wait, the code just keeps processing. I know this problem probably has something to do with my specific database, but I was wondering if there are any overt errors.

Additionally, if it has to do with the call I am making in my database, how would I go about debugging this since I get no formal errors?

```
SELECT cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS ANSWER_ID, cr.CONSUMER_ID as VIEWER_ID, 
       cr.ACTION_LOG_ID, nc.PARENT_COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS QUESTION_ID,
       cirm.CONSUMER_RATING AS VIEWER_INTEREST, 
       cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID AS DOMAIN
FROM (
       SELECT 234 AS CONSUMER_ID, ACTION_LOG_ID, COMMUNICATIONS_ID 
        FROM consumer_action_log 
        WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4
      ) AS cr
    JOIN network_communications AS nc ON 
        cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=nc.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
    JOIN communication_interest_mapping AS cim ON 
       nc.PARENT_COMMUNICATIONS_ID=cim.COMMUNICATION_ID
    JOIN consumer_interest_rating_mapping AS cirm ON 
       cr.CONSUMER_ID=cirm.CONSUMER_ID AND           
       cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID=cirm.CONSUMER_INTEREST_ID;
```

Comment: Which database package are you using?

Comment: Toad, DBVisualizer and PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Have you tried using EXPLAIN or the Toad equivalent?

Comment: I have tried this. However, since the query never executes, I am unable to review the explain results.

Comment: How long have you waited, and how large is your database?

Comment: Can you execute the subquery (`SELECT 234 .. COMM_TYPE_ID=4`)?

Comment: `I am unable to review the explain results`: Restart MySQL. Close web browser, restart, and try phpMyAdmin again.

Comment: The result would only be 634 rows and I have waited about 3 minutes. I can execute that subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derived column in the subquery may be throwing MySQL off. Try this query instead for the same results

```
SELECT cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS ANSWER_ID, cirm.CONSUMER_ID as VIEWER_ID, 
       cr.ACTION_LOG_ID, nc.PARENT_COMMUNICATIONS_ID AS QUESTION_ID,
       cirm.CONSUMER_RATING AS VIEWER_INTEREST, 
       cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID AS DOMAIN
FROM (
       SELECT ACTION_LOG_ID, COMMUNICATIONS_ID 
        FROM consumer_action_log 
        WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID=4
      ) AS cr
    JOIN network_communications AS nc ON 
        cr.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=nc.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
    JOIN communication_interest_mapping AS cim ON 
       nc.PARENT_COMMUNICATIONS_ID=cim.COMMUNICATION_ID
    JOIN consumer_interest_rating_mapping AS cirm ON 
       cim.CONSUMER_INTEREST_EXPERT_ID=cirm.CONSUMER_INTEREST_ID
WHERE cirm.CONSUMER_ID = 234
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any obvious (syntax) errors.  You've likely made a logic error in your joins.  To debug, eliminate the joins until you get results back.  Then start adding the joins back in.  This should show you where you went wrong.

Comment: I actually have already done this (this is part of the bigger join). The first two joins in isolation don't give me trouble, it is only when they are paired with the third join.

Comment: You could try adding a LIMIT clause and see if it returns results